# Spring boot mongo data find repository returns Unsupported operation error when having hateos

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-hateoas

It returns error on repository find method
.
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No accessor to set property @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement(namespace=http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom, name=link, type=class javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement$DEFAULT, defaultValue= , required=false, nillable=false) @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.Json

Repository

```
public interface CommentRepository extends CrudRepository<Comment, String> { 
Iterable<Comment> findBySectionIdAndCommentableTypeAndCommentableIdAndDeleted(final String sectionId,
        final String commentableType, final String commentableId, final boolean deleted);
```

Comment Model

```
@ApiModel(description = "Comment")
@Document(collection = "comment")
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@Relation(value = "comment", collectionRelation = "comments")
public class Comment extends ResourceSupport implements Serializable, 
UserIdentifiable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 116036486931198760L;

/** The id of the comment. */
@Id
@ApiModelProperty(readOnly = true)
private String commentId;

@NotEmpty
@ApiModelProperty(required = true)
private String sectionId;

/** The type of the comment applicable element. */
@NotEmpty
@ApiModelProperty(required = true)
private String commentableType;
```

This occurs after upgrading the spring boot version to 2.1.2